# Oracle parses text of "'{S}Paris2" as a string literal then finds {S} which it is treating as a SQL Escape Sequence which it doesn't recognize

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am getting the following error after running the jsp report.

Query Tag:doAfterBody(),0,Non supported SQL92 token at position: 3477: S

I know that the following snippet causing the problem ‘{S}’:

……..   AND (L.Applicable_Location_Region_ID IN (N'PARIS2', N'{S}Paris2'))

As per my investigation, I came to know following:
Oracle parses the SQL and treats the text of "'{S}Paris2" as a string literal then finds {S} which it is treating as a SQL Escape Sequence which it doesn't recognize.

The following link explains well about “Escape Characters”:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/inter.815/a67843/cqspcl.htm

we must use {S} followed by name.

The above AND statement works fine with SQL Server and MySQL, but causes problem with Oracle as “When you use braces to escape a single character, the escaped character becomes a separate token in the query.”

Due to above reason the application treats {S}, as the escaped a single character with braces becomes a separate token in the query.

So please could you help me how can I escape single character with braces in oracle or any suggestion please.

Comment: Are you building the whole SQL string **including** the data? You should use a prepared statement with parameters instead. In addition to (probably) solving this problem, it will also protect you from most [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
AND (L.Applicable_Location_Region_ID IN (N'PARIS2', N'\{S\}Paris2'))
```

EDIT:

Running this query from Toad

```
select (N'{S}test2') from dual where ((N'{S}test2') IN (N'test2', N'{S}test2'))
```

does work for me. 
Are you sure that the problem is in Oracle database and not in the class/driver accessing it ?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but still getting java.sql.SQLException: Non supported SQL92 token at position: 3546: S

Comment: And by the way, your error was on char 3477, after inserting backslashes it jumped to 3546 ?